# Create Json blocks from a text file

Tags: python, json

I have a text file like below

```
    A : abc
    B : crs
    C : rds
    D : fgh

    A: wer
    B : tyu
    C : uio
    D : dfg
```

There can be any number of above blocks in the input text file.I want to create a json file from this.Here is my code:

```
import json
with open("<input file path>") as fd: # open file
    d = dict(line.split(":", 1) for line in fd) # create dict of it
print json.dumps(d) # print dict in json format
```

but this is not doing the job, its omitting some initial lines and   not printing separate blocks one below the other

Comment: In your test data you have all keys twice. If you add a key to a dictionry the second time, it will overwrite the old key. You should think how you JSON should actually look in the end. Maybe a list of dictionaries.

Comment: I think the keys are repeated because there are many JSON objects in his .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Your file has non-unique keys. Please note that [Python's `json` module only supports JSON object **decoding** with duplicate keys](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#repeated-names-within-an-object). You cannot encode JSON object with duplicate keys using standard encoders.

Further, you're using Python's `dict` class as intermediate data storage. As a result, you're losing the data entries order because `dict` does not maintain items order. [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) class does maintain items order but still does not allow duplicate keys, so it isn't an option either.

So unless you can find a JSON package on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) that supports duplicate key encoding for objects, you will probably have to write your own JSON encoder.

So the resulting solution should look like this:

1. Custom class to store your file contents which supports duplicate keys and maintains items order. Essentially a class wrapper over a list of key-value pairs (you need class wrapper to prevent `JSONEncoder` from treating your data as a list).
2. Encoder class, inherited from `JSONEncoder` which overrides `default` method and defines your own custom conversion for instances of your custom data class. See [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) for more details on how it's done:

`To extend this to recognize other objects, subclass and implement a default() method with another method that returns a serializable object for o if possible, otherwise it should call the superclass implementation (to raise TypeError).`

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code like this:

```
import json
result = [] # Result will be a list of dictionaries
with open("data.txt") as fd:
    d = dict()  # Start the first dictionary
    for line in fd:
        line = line.strip()
        if d and line == '':
            # Start a new block/dictionary on empty lines
            result.append(d)
            d = dict()
            continue
        k, v = line.split(":", 1)
        d[k.strip()] = v.strip()
if d:
    # Add any remaining results
    result.append(d)
print json.dumps(result, indent=2) # Print parsed results as json
```

If I understand you correctly, the following output is what you want:

```
[
  {
    "A": "abc", 
    "C": "rds", 
    "B": "crs", 
    "D": "fgh"
  }, 
  {
    "A": "wer", 
    "C": "uio", 
    "B": "tyu", 
    "D": "dfg"
  }
]
```